# Development feature: disable jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

is it possible to disable jQuery `ajax()` calls? As a developer, I ofttimes need to test site without ajax (without actually turning js off).

I would create a script that utilizes local database: when certain link is clicked, it would toggle a property. Ie. how can I effect global bindings such as

```
$("a.ajax").live("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.get(this.href);
});
```

without actually changing the code itself? Could I replace the `ajax()` function? How would you deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override jQuery's `get` method with an empty annonymous function of your own, before any of your code is run:

```
$.get = function(){};
```

Or you could use jQuery's [`$.noop`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noop/), which is basically the same thing:

```
$.get = $.noop;
```

Comment: Alright, you seem to approve this idea. I wasn't quite sure if it's the right way to go. Thanks

Comment: Marked as an answer because of the `$.noop` note and as it was first anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Using global handlers, you can do something like this..

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Override `$.ajax` to an empty function which do not do anything.

```
$.ajax = function(){};
```